# Thread safety of global variables in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have following questions:

1. How is global code executed and global variables initialized in perl?
2. If I write use package_name; in multiple packages, does the global code execute each time?
3. Are global variables defined this way thread safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl makes a complete copy of all code and variables for each thread.  Communication between threads is via specially marked [shared variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) (which in fact are not shared - there is still a copy in each thread, but all the copies get updated).  This is a significantly different threading model than many other languages have, so the thread-safety concerns are different - mostly centering around what happens when objects are copied to make a new thread and those objects have some form of resource to something outside the program (e.g. a database connection).

Your question about `use` isn't really related to threads, as far as I can tell?  use does several things; one is loading the specified module and running any top-level code in it; this happens only once per module, not once per use statement.