# SOAP::Lite log transport request/response with custom identifier

Tags: perl, logging, soap, soap-client, soaplite

I would like to log SOAP::Lite transport request/response contents using a custom identifier (e.g. a transaction-id or `txn_id` in my example below):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => \&log_transport, ];

sub log_transport {
    my ($in) = @_;
    if (ref($in) eq "HTTP::Request") {
        # INSERT INTO logs ( txn_id, request ) VALUES ( $tnx_id, $in->content )
        say STDERR Dumper(ref($in), $in->content);
    }
    elsif (ref($in) eq "HTTP::Response") {
        # UPDATE logs SET response = '$in->content' WHERE txn_id = $tnx_id
        say STDERR Dumper(ref($in), $in->content);  
    }
}

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy('https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?op=NumberToWords');
$soap->serializer()->register_ns('http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/' ,"ns");

sub getWords
{
    my ($number, $txn_id) = @_ ;

    my $method = SOAP::Data->name("ns:NumberToWords");
    my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name("ubiNum" => $number) );
    my $response = $soap->call($method => @params);

    if (!$response->fault) {
        say STDOUT "NumberToWords = " . $response->result;
    }
    else {
        say STDERR "error: " . (defined $response->faultstring? $response->faultstring : $soap->transport->status);
    }
}

getWords(444, '123abc');
```

In my example above, how can I pass the transaction-id `123abc` to my logger?

P.S. I do not wish to use:

```perl
$soap->outputxml(1)->call($method => @params)
```

Comment: I am not sure if the trace allows parameters to be passed. As a work around you could use e.g. environment variables, lexical variable declared in the outer scope, or a package variable to communicate with the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem like the [`SOAP::Trace`](https://metacpan.org/dist/SOAP-Lite/view/lib/SOAP/Trace.pod) transport callback supports extra argument passing. As a workaround you could use a lexical variable declared in the outer scope like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $TXN_ID;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => \&log_transport, ];

sub log_transport {
    my ($in) = @_;
    say STDERR "Logging transaction id: $TXN_ID:";
    if (ref($in) eq "HTTP::Request") {
        # INSERT INTO logs ( txn_id, request ) VALUES ( $tnx_id, $in->content )
        say STDERR Dumper(ref($in), $in->content);
    }
    elsif (ref($in) eq "HTTP::Response") {
        # UPDATE logs SET response = '$in->content' WHERE txn_id = $tnx_id
        say STDERR Dumper(ref($in), $in->content);  
    }
}

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy('https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?op=NumberToWords');
$soap->serializer()->register_ns('http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/' ,"ns");

sub getWords
{
    my ($number, $txn_id) = @_ ;

    $TXN_ID = $txn_id;
    my $method = SOAP::Data->name("ns:NumberToWords");
    my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name("ubiNum" => $number) );
    my $response = $soap->call($method => @params);

    if (!$response->fault) {
        say STDOUT "NumberToWords = " . $response->result;
    }
    else {
        say STDERR "error: " . (defined $response->faultstring? $response->faultstring : $soap->transport->status);
    }
}

getWords(444, '123abc');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible with a multi-threaded applications. Concurrent calls to `getWords` will yield the wrong value in `$TXN_ID` and hence defeats the purpose.

Comment: *"Concurrent calls to getWords will yield the wrong value in $TXN_ID"* : Can you give an example? Note that even package variables are thread safe in perl, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206125/2173773

Comment: Thank you @Håkon Hægland. I was under the impression that `$TXN_ID` is a global variable, and it isn't thread-safe. I intend to use this in Mojolicious.